# I think I'm facing a logical error in comparison

Tags: c++

I'm doing a string comparison but there is a problem.  I have a file in which `12345` is written and then I have made another source file and performed input (input is `12345`).  Then I'm comparing it through `bool` `true` `false` logic but the issue is that the `bool` never gets true and I think that there is a logical error in the comparison but I didn't get what's wrong in it.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int
main()
{
  char str[256];
  char CNIC[5];
  std::fstream file1;
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
      CNIC[i] = getche();  // editor's comment: probably std::getchar()
    }
  file1.open("D:\\UOL\\OoP\\Nadra database.txt", ios::in);
  bool check = false;
  while(!file1.eof())
    {
      file1.getline(str, 255);

      if(str == CNIC)
        {
          check = true;
          break;
        }
      if(check)
        {
          cout << endl << "CNIC number matched" << endl;
        }
      else
        {
          cout << endl << "CNIC number didn't match" << endl;
        }
    }
  file1.close();
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Either use std::string (recommended) or strcmp. Right now youre comparing the pointers to the beginning of both char arrays (which will never be equal)

Comment: `if(str==CNIC)` Doesn't do what you think it does. You'll need `strcmp()`.

Comment: Also `!file1.eof()` is wrong [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/583833)

Answer (score 4):

you are comparing pointers, not values.
have a look at [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/)

```
check = strcmp(str, CNIC) == 0;
```

and remove the `break` as it will exit your `while` loop, before you do the output.

Comment: Probably a good idea to make sure that `CNIC` is zero-terminated (which it currently is not).

Answer (score 0):

`if(str==CNIC)` doesn't do what you think it does. It's comparing the location in memory where the two strings are stored, and these locations will never be the same.

Your question is tagged C++ so you don't want to be doing things with `char` pointers and arrays anyway. I would probably suggest changing `str` and `CNIC` to `std::string`. Then use `std::getline` to read the string. You can even do length sanity checking on the CNIC if you like, rather than getting 5 single characters.

Also, the `eof` check in your while loop is not the way to check for stream validity. After making the change of `str` to `std::string` just use `while(std::getline(file1, str))` instead.